# sscanf - stop scanning early if certain character is encountered

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to scan strings that may end with "comments".

For example, say I have the following string:

```
char *str = "first john last smith# example";
```

Currently, I perform the following operations to scan what I need from the string:

1. Remove the comment + trailing whitespace (e.g. `"first john last smith"`).
2. Scan the "trimmed" string (e.g. using `first %10s last %10s` and `sscanf`).
3. `"john"` and `"smith"` have been scanned successfully! :)

This works, but is there a standard way I can avoid trimming the string by having `sscanf` terminate early if a '#' is encountered? Ideally, scanning strings such as `"first john last smith"` or `"first john last smith# example"` would yield the same results given the same format string.

Comment: Why not preprocess the input before scanning? Something like `char * commentLoc = strchr(input, '#'); if (commentLoc) *commentLoc = '\0'`

Comment: The `"%["` format might be useful. As in `"%10[^# \t]"`. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference for details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @SakthiKumar That's what I'm currently doing.

Comment: It *can* be done, but you are already stretching the  capabilities of `scanf`. Once you are outside of the realm of very simple pattern matching (with the placeholders that everybody knows), probably writing a simple parser by hand is easier and more flexible.

Comment: I agree with @MatteoItalia. `scanf` does what it does, and what it does is very limited. So if you want to do something else, don't use `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reasonably sure you won't have to deal with incomplete information (the comments may be present, but it doesn't matter if they aren't), then you simply prevent [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) from parsing the `#` symbols with 'scan sets', like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "first john last smith# example";
    char fname[11] = "";
    char lname[11] = "";
    int rc = sscanf(str, "first %10[^# ] last %10[^ #]", fname, lname);

    printf("rc = %d, fname = [%s], lname = [%s]\n", rc, fname, lname);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from that is:

```
rc = 2, fname = [john], lname = [smith]
```

If the comment character appeared before the last name, then you'd only get `john` read (unless it appeared before that, of course).  The `sscanf()` doesn't need to worry about the trailing material; it's still there in the string, but there's no need to look at it at all.

I share the commentators view that this is probably not the most reliable way of working.

Note the use of `char fname[11];` and `%10[…]` to get the string length working properly.  The off-by-one is a nuisance, but hallowed in the standard, based on pre-standard tradition.  Were you designing it from scratch, you'd not have the 'different-by-one' on the lengths.  There'd also be a way to specify field lengths dynamically, analogous to the `%*.*f` notation in `printf()`.  That is, sadly, not provided by `scanf()` and friends.